# Python print format umlaut align right

Tags: python, printing, formatting

I am trying to print text aligned right containing a german umlaut. This is, what the python interpreter produces:

```
>>> print "----\n{:>4}\n{:>4}".format("Ho", "Hö")
----
  Ho
 Hö
```

so, what am i doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just let python know that you're leading with UTF-8 strings by adding a `u` in front of the string literal.

```
print u"----\n{:>4}\n{:>4}".format("Ho", u"Hö")
```